# Why does the javac command need a source file argument when it uses the --module-source-path option?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

For example, on the windows command line running the following:

> >javac -d appmodules --module-source-path appsrc

is not possible as the command line returns

> >error: no source files

Why is this the case as I am instructing the command line to compile modules anyway by using the --module-source-path, why would I also need to compile extra source files that I don't want or need to?